# Changing variables by loop

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop

Let's say I have 150 pictures. I need to change their visibility or even resource with loop to not do it for every one photo by typing.

I tried to loop it like this:

```
final ImageView randompic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic1);
final ImageView randompic2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic2);
final ImageView randompic3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic3);
final ImageView randompic4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic4);
//(etc.)

    for (int j = 0; j <=150; j++){
            randompic(j).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                             };
```

So I would like to change it in loop to be like: randompic(j).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) for randompic1, randompic2, randompic3 etc. in each loop. Java do not accept this kind of typing like JavaScript. I do not know how to find good way to write that kind of loop.

Comment: setting 150 different things to true/false already seems like an inefficient

Answer (score 1):

Add your ImageViews to a List and change the visibility of every item in this list like this:

```java
List<ImageView> randompics = new ArrayList<>();
randompics.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic1));
randompics.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic2));
randompics.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic3));
randompics.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic4));
//(etc.)

for (int j = 0; j <= randompics.size(); j++) {
    randompics.get(j).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
};
```

Instead of the classic `for`-loop you can also use `foreach` like this:

```java
randompics.foreach(pic -> pic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE));
```